# how to access a particular column in grid view?

Tags: asp.net

In grid view I want to sort the particular column. For that we have to access that column
How to do this??

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to use the built in sorting methods attached to the GridView class itself as described in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx

Might not hurt to accept some answers to previous questions though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just access to the column you need: `myGridview.Columns[0]`, where 0 is the index of your column.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow either one of the foolowing while think of sorting,

1.Client side sorting using javascript or Jquery (recommended if you have lesser number of rows in your gridview)
2.Custom sorting in server side code(I personally recommend you for using large amount of data)

Please follow the link for [custom sorting in asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)